# default method in java Interface using java 10.0.2 version still doesn't work

Tags: java

I want to add a default method in an interface but it doesn't work, I am using Linux Mint and I verified my java version, I found that it is the 10.0.2 version and I still have the message "illegal start of type".

checking my java version:

```
     java -version
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

The java code that I am trying to compile:

```
interface TestDefault {
    default int m1() { return 1; }  //legal
}
```

The error that I get:

```
javac TestDefault.java
    TestDefault.java:2: error: illegal start of type
    default int m1() { return 1; }
```

Comment: Are you compiling with javac or with an IDE?

Comment: `java -version` doesn't tell you which _compiler_ you are using.

Comment: I am compiling with javac, in the Terminal

Comment: Perhaps you are missing `public` from your interface declaration? i.e. `public interface TestDefault {}` Actually, just discovered that it works for me using Java 1.8.0_201 on Windows 7. So probably `public` is not actually required.

Comment: @mynorperalta And with what version of javac are you compiling?

Comment: @khelwood, I just executed the "javac -version" command, and I noticed that it is the 1.7.0_181 version. Sorry I am new using java. I have to go now. I will continue later, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some sort of editor?. If you are using eclipse, please check java version of your project using: right click on your project -> properties -> Java compiler. Check the Java version used. Enable project specific setting and set java version probably 8 and above.

Comment: Thank you, I am compiling with javac, in the Terminal

Comment: Please  check compile version on Terminal $ javac -version

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem was solved seen the real version of the java compiler with the $javac -version command, not with the $java -version command.

Answer (score 0):

If you call

```
javac -version
```

You'll notice you are compiling with a Java version `<` (less then) 8.
This means you have two environment variables, one for the JRE and one for the JDK.

Set the JDK environment variable to point the JDK 10.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I had to do to see the real java compiler

Comment: I already did it my friend, but I don't have the privileges to change the number zero to number one, thanks again.